# How to improve the solution to ignore x-frame-option using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, x-frame-options

This is the code from http://jsfiddle.net/2gou4yen/ to ignore x-frame-option.

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var url = iframe.src;
var getData = function (data) {
    if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.resources && data.query.results.resources.content && data.query.results.resources.status == 200) 
       loadHTML(data.query.results.resources.content);
    else if (data && data.error && data.error.description) loadHTML(data.error.description);
    else loadHTML('Error: Cannot load ' + url);
};
var loadURL = function (src) {
    url = src;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.headers%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) +'%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=getData';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
var loadHTML = function (html) {
    iframe.src = 'about:blank';
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html.replace(/<head>/i, '<head><base href="' + url + '"><scr' + 'ipt>document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") { e.preventDefault(); parent.loadURL(e.target.href); } });</scr' + 'ipt>'));
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
} 
loadURL(iframe.src);
```

This works well.
But with a problem.

For the first time, it doesn't work. And when you refresh once, it works.

So, is there a solution that works without refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tested in other browser?
In my opinion it's browser problem.
Test it in Safari, Google Chrome, FireFox.

In other way you can save the content in your server as html using serverside code and load it from server.